# Sorting 2 columns in powershell Array object to find the diff

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have a system.Array in this format

```
A_Site      B_Site
----------- -----------
BN6         BIO70      
BY21        BN6        
BY4         BY21       
CBR20       BY4
```

is there a way to sort this is such a way like this ? idea is to know if there are missing site codes in column A or missing site codes in column B..

```
A_Site      B_Site
----------- -----------
BN6         BN6      
BY21        BY21        
BY4         BY4       
CBR20       
            BIO70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* the two columns in your sample input are stored in *separate arrays*, the following yields the desired output (PSv3+):

```
$arr1 = "BN6", "BY21", "BY4", "CBR20"
$arr2 = "BIO70", "BN6", "BY21", "BY4"

Compare-Object $arr1 $arr2 -IncludeEqual | 
  Select-Object @{ n='A_Site'; e={ if ($_.SideIndicator -in '==', '<=') { $_.InputObject } } }, 
                @{ n='B_Site'; e={ if ($_.SideIndicator -in '==', '=>') { $_.InputObject } } }
```

Comment: Compare object does compare. But can be blinded. It's best to feed it the properties to compare. Or it might not perform the job right.

Comment: @RobertCotterman: Yes, `Compare-Object` compares instances of reference types by their `.ToString()` values, if no `-Property` argument(s) are specified, which typically doesn't yield the desired results. In this case, however, the input objects already are _strings_, so comparing them as-is is what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Other method:

```
$arr1 = "BN6", "BY21", "BY4", "CBR20"
$arr2 = "BIO70", "BN6", "BY21", "BY4"

$arr1+ $arr2 | select -Unique | %{

    $Value=$_;

    [pscustomobject]@{
    Value=$_
    IsInArray1=(($arr1 | where {$_ -eq $Value} | select -First 1) -ne $null) 
    IsInArray2=(($arr2 | where {$_ -eq $Value} | select -First 1) -ne $null) 
    }

}
```